# which URL is given to for setting "Do not backup flag" in ios?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsdocumentdirectory

i am storing some downloaded files in NSDocumentDirectory and i need to mark those files as "do not backup".

here is the code i have given

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL1
    {
       if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) { // iOS <= 5.0.1
       const char* filePath = [[URL1 path] fileSystemRepresentation];

       const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
       u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

      int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
      return result == 0;
     } else { // iOS >= 5.1
                NSError *error = nil;
               [URL1 setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];

               return error == nil;
                NSLog(@"success");
            }
      }
```

littile bit confused about which url should given for ths method? downloading url or the downloaded file path url?
can i use like

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MdMus.mp3"];
  [receivedData writeToFile:documentsDirectoryPath atomically:YES];
```

need to use this one

```
     NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectoryPath];  
   [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:url];
```

or this

```
     [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:DownloadingURL];
```

need help

Comment: It should be the first `url`, because it states that files won't backup from that *folder* through iCloud. I can't answer this with good references, as i've not used skip backup before. So writing it as a comment. But i'm pretty sure it is the url got from documentdirectory.

Comment: definetly it should be url as it states check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)

Comment: @iNoob thankyou, let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want filesharing all user-data(in DocumentDirectory all data) prevent backup. refer a following code.

```
- (void)addAttributeToAllFolder
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];

    for (int i =0; i < [dirContents count]; i++) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath,[dirContents objectAtIndex:i]]];
        //this is your method (addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:)
        if ([self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:url]) {
            NSLog(@"success! could add do not backup attribute to folder");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah right. Finally, please check the console using a NSLog. Url of your form will look like the following. (/var/mobile/Applications/AB36DF05-A13C-4DC4-8F29-E854050410C8/Documents/blahblah.mp3)